# arranging files side by side

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, glob

I have text files(file1,file2,file3...) in a directory i want to sort based on file names and arrange the files side by side in  a separate text file.

```
cat file1   cat file2  cat file3
1               4           8
3               5           1
4               6           3
```

expected output

```
cat output.txt
1  4  8
3  5  1
4  6  3
```

My code:

```
import glob
myfiles = glob.glob('file*')
for file in myfiles:
  #from here i cannot proceed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the file list by the integer in it. Then use `pd.concat` to concat list of dataframes and at last export it to `output.txt`

```py
import re
import glob
import pandas as pd

myfiles = glob.glob('file*')

myfiles.sort(key=lambda s: re.findall(r'\d+', s)[0])
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(myfile, header=None) for myfile in myfiles], axis=1)

df.to_csv('output.txt', index=None, header=None, sep=' ')
```

Comment: if my filesnames are in this format it also doesnot work  123_10.asc_rsmp_1.0.txt, 32_10.asc_rsmp_1.0.txt   so can u please clarify,....32_10.asc_rsmp_1.0.txt should come first then 123_10.asc_rsmp_1.0.txt

Comment: @virajmoil You should clarify your sorting logic and question. In your original question, the filename is like `file<n>`.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to sort the files according to their names
- According to your requirements, use Zip function to align them

```py
import glob
myfiles = sorted(glob.glob('file*'))
print(myfiles)
num_lists = []
for file in myfiles:
  #from here i cannot proceed
  with open(file, "r") as fin:
      num_lists.append(fin.readlines())

print(num_lists)
aligned_lists = zip(num_lists[0], num_lists[1], num_lists[2])

with open("output.txt", "w") as fout:
    for lst in aligned_lists:
        print(lst)
        new_lst = list(map(str.strip, lst))
        print(new_lst)
        fout.write(" ".join(new_lst) + "\n")
```

Comment: `sorted` doesn't sort `['file1', 'file10', 'file2']`